# https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/media/ not working anymore

Tags: instagram, media, instagram-api

I have a app use this request url https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/media to get public ig json,
but now it just not working anymore.

I've checked Instagram blog, and no any announcement are found.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not tech support for Instagram. If the problem is in your code, you need to show the code in your question that causes the problem . [mcve]

Comment: I have the same problem since 2017-11-07 18:55:34 GMT

Comment: You can use this instead https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1 But it's doesn't give so much info as /media/

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1 gives only last 10 photos and it is unclear how to deal with pagination (how to get more photos)

Comment: This may not be a technical programming question, but I would still expect to find this answer and conversation on SO.  It's a big deal affecting many developers.

Comment: I appreciate JECon's short-term, also undocumented, fix to grab the 12 most recent photos. To help anyone else out, this is my code specifically:

Comment: // set URL and other appropriate options: 
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/anyuser/?__a=1");
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          // execute curl          
    $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
          $data = json_decode($jsonData, true)['user']['media']['nodes'];

Comment: The link to the ith image is in $data[i]['display_src'] and you can build the link to the actual full post using 'www.instagram.com/p/' . $data[i]['code'] . '/?taken-by=anyuser'.  This is obviously not perfect, but this quick hack fixed our broken home page while we go through the hassle of acquiring an access token and doing it right per the official API, which I'm guessing might be a learning curve for many (like me).

Comment: Excuse my comments instead of an answer where I could insert the code more readably, but since this is "On Hold", I evidently cannot provide an answer. Hope it helps some other, less experienced Instagram person like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`https://www.instagram.com/{USER-NAME}/media/` was never officially supported or documented by Instagram. So never rely on undocumented or private APIs.

Comment: The reason so many people relied on that for years, was that it's the only way to grab public posts without an actual approved app with public API access. And Instagram doesn't approve that kind of apps any more.

Comment: True, I was using that too but not for a real app in appstore or a web service, you never know when they will stop undocumented APIs,